# Como calcular um valor ótimo para a variável CONCURRENT_REQUESTS do Scrapyd?

Tags: python, aplicação-web, web-crawler, scrapy

Uma das configurações que vem padrão no Scrapyd é o número de processos concorrentes (é 16).

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 16

Qual seria a melhor metodologia para calcular um valor ótimo para esta variável?

O objetivo é obter o melhor desempenho em relação à uso de processamentos e memória versus número de páginas crawleadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a extensão [AutoThrottle](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html), que tenta otimizar a velocidade de crawling baseando-se em estimativas da carga do servidor e do processamento do Scrapy.

Usando essa extensão ([código aqui](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/throttle.py)), você pode definir um `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP` (ou `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`) máximo, e os limites reais serão definidos dinamicamente de acordo com o desempenho medido em tempo de execução. O [algoritmo de throttling](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html#throttling-algorithm) leva em conta a latência.

Fora isso, para achar uma configuração melhor você terá que testar diferentes combinações de limites de requisições concorrentes por IP/domínio, download delay e carga da CPU.

É difícil definir uma receita para fazer isso manualmente, porque depende muito do tipo de crawling que você está fazendo. Por exemplo, se você está crawleando vários sites diferentes, pode querer usar configurações diferentes para cada. Se você está crawleando apenas um site, terá que levar em conta as limitações de requisições. E assim por diante, cada situação terá que ser analisada em separado.

Muitos sites impõem um máximo de requisições por IP por intervalo de tempo, então geralmente faz sentido configurar junto `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP` e `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`, respeitando as limitações do site.

Answer (score 0):

O numero pode variar muito de servidor para servidor. E, se você estiver criando um spider genérico para indexar vários sites fica mais difícil ainda.
Normalmente eu vou aumentando até eu conseguir fazer meu CPU ficar próximo de 100% em um dos cores. Assim eu consigo me certificar que o algoritmo se tornou limitado pelo CPU e não mais pela rede.

Se desejar reduzir a memoria utilizada, simplesmente ative a configuração `JOBDIR` que o consumo de memória deixará de crescer.

Eu não tive sucesso com o `AutoThrottle`. A extensão me pareceu muito simples e a maioria das vezes a velocidade não fica muito abaixo da velocidade ótima.